# Как добавить статический метод, который возвращает пустой параметризованный объект типа?

Tags: java, generics

Учусь Java, не понимаю вопроса:

> Box, который может хранить в себе один объект класса, которым он параметризирован в поле с названием object. Нужно добавить статический метод getBox(), который возвращает пустой параметризованный объект типа Box.

Вот только не понимаю что мне необходимо написать в методе getBox?

```
class Box <T> {
    private T object;
}
```

Comment: наверно должен быть метод `public static T getBox() { return (T) object; }` наверно так

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко, а нафига тут каст?

Comment: @Qwertiy согл он тут не нужен, о своем задумался :)

Answer (score 0):

```
static <T> Box<T> getBox() {return new Box<>(); }
```